# Displaying queried date field issue using PHP, CodeIgniter, and MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I altered a table in MySQL to be a timestamp so I could see when a user was created:

```
ALTER TABLE  `users` CHANGE  `created_date`  `created_date` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ;
```

Using CodeIgniter I queried the database and got my row results for all users:

```
$this->db->get('users');
```

In my view I'm trying to display the results using PHP date():

```
<?php echo date("d-m-Y", $row->created_date); ?>
```

and I'm getting this error message, which I don't understand:

```
Severity: Notice
Message: A non well formed numeric value encountered
Filename: users/view_all_users.php
Line Number: 19
```

where by itself:

```
<?php echo $row->created_date ?>
```

produces:

```
01-01-1970 0000-00-00 00:00:00
```

Any ideas what I've done wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the second argument for `date()` must be a [valid time stamp](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php). `01-01-1970 0000-00-00 00:00:00` is not a valid timestamp.

```
$arr = explode(' ',$row->created_date);
$date = $arr[1] . ' ' . $arr[2];
echo date("d-m-Y", strtotime($date));
```

note that this string: `01-01-1970 0000-00-00 00:00:00` probably denotes that the value in your field is wrong, but this string: `1970-01-01 00:00:00` is valid for use with `strtotime()`

**edit** I have an eerie feeling though, are you sure that the full string is outputed by the second echo, or are your two echos taking place, hence mimicking an invalid string? in which case this:

```
echo date("d-m-Y", strtotime($row->created_date));
```

will work right away!

Comment: How would I alter my table to get a valid time stamp, instead of handling it code?  Also not sure why it's giving me 1970 date, that's not a current timestamp from my system.

Comment: why do you need a timestamp instead of a easy to use/format/think about `DATETIME` field? also getting a valid timestamp in your field is more about putting a valid timestamp in then altering your table

Comment: I can definitely use a date field, but I couldn't figure out how to add it in MyPHPAdmin and have it add a current date default.  Only option was CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.

Comment: can you post the code which defines the row? the string returned is not a timestamp, it must be changed somehow by codeigniter

Comment: In the example above I just have to call $this->db->get('users'); and it returns everything in a data array, which I just pass from model to controller to view.

Comment: I also changed my ALTER TABLE SQL by added DATETIME instead of TIMESTAMP, so it looks like this now ALTER TABLE  `users` CHANGE  `created_date`  `created_date` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;  So it should be a date time now, and without using the PHP date() it shows the current date and time as 2014-07-25 10:59:25, so I think you're right CodeIgniter is handling the date field.

Comment: the string `2014-07-25 10:59:25` is the normal format of a `DATETIME` field. now you can either format it further to be more wordy, or remove the hour and just put the date :)

Answer (score 0):

MySQL returns that cumbersome string when you use the TIMESTAMP data type. You can either convert it to the Unix value you are expecting in your query:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`created_date`)...
```

(and also convert your timestamp to a string when you save it)

Or you can simply use an integer data type in the database and bypass all the string business.